# What does 'o = o or {}' do in Lua?

Tags: class, object, oop, lua, prototype

As I understand from docs, we don't have classes in Lua. Lua does not have the concept of class; each object defines its own behavior and has a shape of its own.

So a simple emulation of classes in Lua, following the lead from prototype-based languages, such as Self and NewtonScript would be something like.

```
function Account:new (o)
      o = o or {}   
      setmetatable(o, self)
      self.__index = self
      return o
    end
```

What I don't understand here is what does `o = o` do and why do we need to use setmetadatatable and the next line `index = self`.

What does it do and why do we need them?

Also `self.o = o` was pretty much understood, but `o = o`, wouldn't that create any conflict?

https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html

Comment: The purpose of this idiom is to allow easy inheritance as is explained later on in the PIL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first line, see Vlads answer.

`setmetatable(o, self)` assigns `self` as the [metatable](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.html) of `o`. `self` can now contain a set of metamethods to add functionality to `o` (see link for more information).

`__index` is the metamethod called when `o` does not contain an indexed key. It can also be another table. In this example, `__index` is set to `self`, so if you attempt to index a nil value in `o`, it will look in `self` instead. If you only call `Account:new()`, `self` is `Account`.

Example from you link: you have an deposit function in `Account`. After you created your object `o = Account:new()` you can now call `o:deposit()`. This will look in `o` for deposit, fails, then looks in `__index=Account` for `deposit`, succeeds, calls it.

If you do not set the metatable, or `__index`, calling `o:deposit()` will result in an `attempt to call a nil value`.

Answer (score 3):

`A = B or C` is commonly used idiom, relying on short-circuit evaluation of logic operators. If the first operand B is not null or false, then the A gets value of B, and the other operand is not evaluated. If the B is null or false, then the A gets value of C.

In this particular application of the idiom the `o` gets default value of new empty table when the parameter `o` wasn't given, because the missing parameter evaluates to null value.
The parameter `o` is a local variable, so all the effects of assigning anything to it will stay local to the `Account:new()` function.

Comment: What about the next 2 lines?